# Accessing values in nested object[] inside of IList from Nhibernate ISQLQuery.List()?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, .net-3.5

I have an NHibernate ISQLQuery.List()

```
ISQLQuery sqlQuery = session.CreateSQLQuery(query);
IList tags = sqlQuery.List();
```

where the results in "tags" are an object[] containing 2 child objects.

```
[0] {object[2]} object {object[]}
  [0]   1   object {int}
  [1]   "irregular" object {string}
[1] {object[2]} object {object[]}
  [0]   2   object {int}
  [1]   "irregular mass"    object {string}
```

I can loop through the outer objects w/

```
foreach(var item in tags)
{
  //How to access values in item?
}
```

but how do I get the values from each item, e.g. 1 and "irregular" etc.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing something like this?

```
foreach(var item in tags)
{
  int field1 = (int)item[0];
  string field2 = (string)item[1];

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up w/ that sort of approach.